# Why isn't my score variable showing the right value?

Tags: javascript, increment, decrement

I'm making a basic rock-paper-scissors game. So far this program seems to be going fine, it detects the choices between the player and the computer, but the score doesn't go up properly. I can't get a score higher than 1 if the player wins multiple times in a row, and if there's a tie the score becomes 0.

The computerSelection is determined by a random number, and the playerSelection is entered when the function is called below.

If the player picks **rock** and the computer picks **paper**, for the first time, the console says ""Player wins and the score is 1".
If for the second round the player picks **scissors** and the computer picks **paper**, the console says "Player wins and the score is **1**" when I expected it to say ""Player wins and the score is **2**"

```
function computerPlay() {
    const random = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 3);
    if (random === 1) {
        return "rock";
    }
    else if (random === 2) {
        return "paper";
    }
    else {
        return "scissors";
    }
}

let score = 0;

function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {

    // Computer wins
    if ((playerSelection === 'paper' && computerSelection === 'scissors') ||
        (playerSelection === 'scissors' && computerSelection === 'rock') ||
        (playerSelection === 'rock' && computerSelection === 'paper')) {
        score--;

        //Stop negative scores
        if (score < 0) {
            score = 0;
        }
        return "Computer wins and the score is " +score;
    }

    // Player wins
    else if ((playerSelection === 'paper' && computerSelection === 'rock')|| 
        (playerSelection === 'rock' && computerSelection === 'scissors') ||
        playerSelection === 'scissors' && computerSelection === 'paper') {
        score++;
        return "Player wins and the score is " +score;
    }

    // Same selection
    else {
        return "Tie and the score is " +score;
    }

}
console.log(playRound('paper', computerPlay()));
```

Comment: What is the output when you run the program?

Comment: Let's say the player picks **rock** and the computer picks **paper**, I'll get "Player wins and the score is 1." Then if I pick **scissors** and the computer picks **paper**, I get "Player wins and the score is 1."

Comment: That is because there is no game-loop in your program. Meaning, every time you `playRound`, the program restarts, and the score starts at 0. You have to have a loop, which will allow multiple rounds to be played per game "session". The score should be incremented or decremented there.

Comment: Please update your question with the actual, erroneous output, and what you expected instead. That will make the problem you're trying to solve much more clear.

Comment: @EvanBechtol so let's say I want a 5-round game, should I wrap the function in a while loop, while (score < 5) and the function will run without restarting until I get a score of 5?

Comment: @EvanBechtol That's not true. `score` is outside of `playRound`. The problem you mentioned will happen only if he restarts the page.

Comment: @00Saad Do you restart the page after each round?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir as of now, yes, I was just testing the program out and manually inputting rock/paper/scissors, so I had to restart to see if it was working. However, I plan on adding a prompt, so the player types the choice, and eventually having the player click rock/paper/scissors from UI. I'm not sure if a prompt or a UI will make the page restart.

Comment: @00Saad That's the problem. When you restart everything get redefined (you get a brand new `score` variable that is initialized with `0`). When you implement the UI or the prompt it should work perfectly. Also if you are just testing then use developer tools: open the console and keep typing `playRound('paper', computerPlay())` and pressing enter to play as many rounds as you like without restarting.

Comment: typing the function into the console like that definitely worked, thanks

Comment: You're welcome! Remeber, the dev tools are there for you to test your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so your problem is that you don't have any logic to keep the game "session" going. Meaning, *(based on what I see in your post right now)* each game round is exclusive, and the results do not compound each round. To solve this, you need to implement a game-loop to control game flow and allow multiple rounds per session.

Having said that, here is what I came up with and tested a bit to help you:

```
function computerPlay () {
  const options = [ 'rock', 'paper', 'scissors' ];
  return options[Math.floor(Math.random()*options.length)];
}


function computerWins ( playerSelection, computerSelection ) {
  return ( playerSelection === 'paper' && computerSelection === 'scissors' ) ||
      ( playerSelection === 'scissors' && computerSelection === 'rock' ) ||
      ( playerSelection === 'rock' && computerSelection === 'paper' );
}

function playerWins ( playerSelection, computerSelection ) {
  return ( playerSelection === 'paper' && computerSelection === 'rock' ) ||
      ( playerSelection === 'rock' && computerSelection === 'scissors' ) ||
      playerSelection === 'scissors' && computerSelection === 'paper';
}

function playRound ( score, playerSelection, computerSelection ) {
  let result = {};

  // Computer wins
  if ( computerWins( playerSelection, computerSelection ) ) {
    score--;

    //Stop negative scores
    if ( score < 0 ) {
      score = 0;
    }
    result = { message : 'Computer wins, and the score is: ', score };
  }

  // Player wins
  else if ( playerWins( playerSelection, computerSelection ) ) {
    score++;
    result = { message : 'Player wins and the score is: ', score };
  }

  // Same selection
  else {
    result = { message : 'Tie game and the score is: ', score };
  }
  return result;

}

function annouceWinner ( score, message ) {
  console.log( `${message} ${score}` );
}

function main () {
  let score = 0;

  while ( score < 5 ) {
    let roundResult = playRound( score, 'paper', computerPlay() );
    score           = roundResult.score;
    annouceWinner( score, roundResult.message );
  }
}

main();
```

You'll notice that I created a couple utility methods, and cleaned it up a bit overall.

- There is now a `computerWins` method to hold the logic that determines when the computer wins. This is good, because if for some reason this logic were to need refactoring, it only needs to be done in this one method!
- There is now a `playerWins` method to hold the logic that determines when the player wins.
- There is now a `announceWinner` method. This one isn't necessarily needed, but this allows you to break away the messaging part from the main loop function easily.
- There is now a `main` method. This is the heart, this controls the flow of your program and allows you to have multiple "rounds" per session.

Sample output:

```
Computer wins, and the score is:  1
Tie game and the score is:  1
Player wins and the score is:  2
Player wins and the score is:  3
Computer wins, and the score is:  2
Tie game and the score is:  2
Player wins and the score is:  3
Player wins and the score is:  4
Player wins and the score is:  5
```

Comment: Alright, I'm going to take a look at this and make sense of it, thanks for your help.